# Rotational mechanics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

A cubic block of mass *m* and side *b* is placed on a smooth floor. A smooth and rigid rod of length *L* and with negligible mass is leaning against the block. A sphere of mass *M* is attached to the upper end of rod. The lower end of the rod is fixed at point O, but it can rotate freely around the point in the vertical plane. Initially the angle between the rod and the floor is $\alpha$ while the system is at rest. After releasing, find the speed of the block when the angle between rod and the floor is $\beta$.[image]

I am getting very confused how to solve this problem. First I made FBD for the rod and the block and used it to find net acceleration which I did $g\tan(\alpha)$ but could not use it find velocity. So, I tried using conservation of force but still got stuck. How do I go about it?

Comment: Try to relate $\frac{d(\theta)}{dt}$ with lengths, where $\theta$ is the angle with the horizontal.

Comment: Also try to balance torques about point O. Sum of torques about O = $I\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is angular acceleration of the rod about O. Once you are able to find angular acceleration, remember that is it $\frac{d\omega}{dt}$.

Comment: I'm formulating an answer but it is a little harder than anticipated.

Comment: For recommendations of alternative sites which might be suitable see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/) You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com.